# Trouble in understanding the working of try-catch-finally blocks

Tags: java

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but, I believe that the statements in the `try` block get executed first, then, if any exception occurs, the statements in the `finally` block get executed and then the statements in the `catch` block get executed. If no exception occurs, then the statements in the finally block are executed once the statements in the `try` block are executed and the statements in the catch block are skipped.

If my above conception is not mistaken, then I don't understand why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
// sock is an object of the class Socket
public void run() {
    try {
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        scan = new Scanner(in);
        out = sock.getOutputStream();
        pw = new PrintWriter(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sock.close();
    }   
}
```

It still says that I need to surround the statement in the `finally` block with `try-catch`.

Answer (score 6):

**No!** the statements in the `try` block are executed first. Then if any exceptions occurs then the `catch` block statements are executed. And `finally` block is executed lastly. `finally` block gets executed even if an exception occurs in the `try` block. In other words if no exception occurs then first the `try` block is executed and then the `finally` block is executed.

Comment: Then what's the point of the 'No' in your answer when you have repeated exactly what I have said?

Comment: @KaneWilliamson I think that you have not read my answer properly. You have said **1 `try`, 2 `finally` and 3 `catch`**. But I said  **1 `try`, 2 `catch` and 3 `finally`**

Comment: dear downvoter could you explain what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 4):

In *general* If your `catch` block can `catch` the `Exception` `thrown` by the `try` block.

```
try -> finally (If No Exception)
try -> catch -> finally (If Exception)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements within the `catch` block are executed whenever an exception is encountered (which can be caught by the listed catch blocks). The statements within the `finally` block will always get executed, whether or not an exception was thrown within the `try` block.

Your `sock.close();` statement could potentially throw an `IOException`, so either you should have another try-catch block wrapping the inner try-catch or add a `throws` declaration to your run() method (and the caller of the method can have a try-catch block surrounding the call).

EDIT (as per comment):
Statements within `catch` get executed first, then the statements within `finally`.

Comment: Which is what I have mentioned as well. But in what order?